# What can cause us to stop to enjoy music?

Tags: emotion, music, aging

I have a growing impression, that people tend to enjoy music less as they grow older, as I look at other people, who used to love to listen to music, now listen to it much less or stops to listen at all.

Going online, I've found articles about why [we don't like new music as we get older](https://www.businessinsider.com/why-we-stop-discovering-new-music-around-age-30-2018-6), and [how music therapy helps older people](https://www.webmd.com/healthy-aging/music-therapy-for-older-adults) but nothing about less enjoyment with aging.

Also there is some [feedback on similar question @ quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-older-people-don-t-enjoy-music-as-much-as-they-used-to), where people seemed to enjoy music despite of age. Another person asking [why one suddenly stops to enjoy music](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-enjoy-music-anymore-even-though-it-used-to-be-a-big-part-of-my-life) and answers suggesting options from too scarse musical horizon to psychological trauma. Last question answers made some sense for me, because my surrounding has more with mind troubles rather than with age.

Having that on hands, I think my question should sound like:

**What can make us indifferent or even resistant to music?**

Comment: You base your question title fully on an anecdote, as you clarify in your post. If your question is about confirming a suspicion, then ask whether the suspicion is true, not _why_ it is the case. Furthermore, we expect a minimum amount of initial research on this site. Any resources you ran into which are related but did not fully answer your question?

Comment: @StevenJeuris sorry, fixed that. Also, after I did some research, it made me change the question itself, hope it's ok

Comment: Thank you for your edits! It's a definite improvement, albeit possibly too subjective to be able to answer meaningfully. Also, from glossing over what you link to, it seems your initial hypothesis was very hard to substantiate.  You only found one edge case of someone confirming your suspicion. But let's see what the community thinks!

Comment: I think this question is very opinion-based. Not liking some of the new music being created does not mean you no longer like the older music you previously enjoyed. Music is constantly evolving and is very subjective just like visual art. There is new music being created in the older styles all the time. That can be liked too. What scientific research have you read which points to the fact that people no longer enjoy music when they get older?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I'm sorry if I didn't clarify my question enough, I meant not new music, but all music in general. I haven't found any research about corellation between music enjoyment and aging, except one about "we stop enjoy new music after 30" , so I think my question isn't about it anymore, but instead I'm interested in possible psychological causes of us stop enjoying any music, if there are any